# How to combine Schema.org itemtypes in Microdata?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I need to describe a `LocalBusiness` which is a bowling but also serves food.

```
 <div class="col-md-4" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BowlingAlley">
            <link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://schema.org/Restaurant">
            <div class="widget-item">
                <h3 class="widget-title" itemprop="name">My Bowling</h3>
                <div class="sample-thumb">
                    <img itemprop="image" src="~/Content/images/bowling.jpg">
                </div>
                <p itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                    <span itemprop="streetAddress">Somestreet 33</span>
                    <br>
                    <span itemprop="postalCode">1000</span> <span itemprop="addressLocality">Brussels</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <span itemprop="telephone">(+32) 123/456 789</span>
                    <br>
                    <span itemprop="email">info@mybowling.be</span>
                    <br>
                    <a href="www.mybowling.be" itemprop="url" target="_blank">www.mybowling.be</a>
                    <meta itemprop="servesCuisine" content="European">
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried with the `additionalType` `Restaurant` but for [Google Validator](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/) this `servesCuisine` fails as an "Unknown property" for `BowlingAlley`.

How can itemtypes be combined correctly?

Resources I've used:

- http://schema.org/additionalType
- http://schema.org/Restaurant
- http://schema.org/FoodEstablishment
- http://schema.org/LocalBusiness
- http://schema.org/BowlingAlley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is totally fine. It is a known issue with google tester.
I've tested it with :

1) [Microdata to RDF Distiller](https://www.w3.org/2012/pyMicrodata/)

2) [Live Microdata](https://foolip.org/microdatajs/live/)

3) [Structured Data Linter](http://linter.structured-data.org/)

You can get some more info here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13674/online-microdata-parser